# How to checkout a branch when all branches are already checked out at '<current_working_tree>'

Tags: git, docker, git-branch, git-worktree

I am trying to checkout a git branch within a docker container.

When I attempt to `git checkout <branch>` from my <docker container> I get a `fatal: <branch> is already checked out at <pathname>/workspaces/worktrees/<docker container>` error.

Exiting the docker container and entering a new one merely changes the `<docker container>`   in which the branch is checked out. This occurs with all branches that I have in local

In the docker container of `<branch4>`, for example,
`git worktree list` returns the following:

```
/<path>/workspaces/repo             9ab1cee0 [master]
/<path>/workspaces/worktrees/branch4  77fe428a [branch1]
/<path>/workspaces/worktrees/branch4  17b659bf [branch2]
/<path>/workspaces/worktrees/branch4  39607a0b [branch3]
/<path>/workspaces/worktrees/branch4  c8ea6d36 [branch4]
```

I've tried `git worktree prune`, `git worktree remove`, `git worktree remove --force`, I've nuked the entire repo and cloned it again, I'm somewhat at a loss.

Comment: share a reproduceable example

Comment: Besides the need for a [mre], I can mention that if you don't *need* to use a *branch name* for whatever you're doing in the container a detached-HEAD checkout will work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Usually a Docker image contains an immutable copy of its application.  I'd suggest not running `git` commands in Docker at all (and definitely not using `docker exec` to change the code in a running container); instead, check out the right branch on your host system and `docker build` an image from what you have checked out.

Comment: Sorry, don't really know how to get this to reproduce, I just know that when performing git checkout in a docker container it won't let me, no matter the container and no matter the branch.